# Multiple MPMoviePlayerController in one view

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have multiple MPMoviePlayerControllers in one view.

When a play one of them while there is already another one is playing,

the playing one is "Paused"(I'm not sure the real state it is, but more like "Stucked")

How can i know which one of the MPMoviePlayerControllers is Stucked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its restriction by apple, in single view controller only single movie player will get played. If one player is in play state and you are trying to play another then first player will get in pause/stop mode.

Comment: I know, but is there a **notification** that i can catch when another player playes?

Comment: I guess there are no notifications, one thing you can do is setting a flag variable.